# Counting the number of triplets forming GP series in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, dictionary

**The problem statement is:**

You are given an array and you need to find number of triplets of indices(i,j,k)  such that the elements at those indices are in geometric progression for a given common ratio, r and i<j<k. For example, arr=[1,4,16,64]. If r=4, we have [1,4,16] and [4,16,64] at indices (0,1,2) and (1,2,3).

I have a solution but I am unable to understand it. Can anyone help me out?

```
def countTriplets(arr, r):
 count = 0
 
 dict = {}
 dictPairs = {}

 for i in reversed(arr):
    if i*r in dictPairs:
        count += dictPairs[i*r]
    if i*r in dict:
        dictPairs[i] = dictPairs.get(i, 0) + dict[i*r]

    dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1

 return count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this problem works is that it uses "dict" to keep a running count of each number in the array. Then, it uses "dictPairs" to keep a running count of the pairs for i and (i*r). Lastly, if (i*r) exists in dictPairs, that means there is a triplet, because if (i*r) exists in dictPairs that must mean (i*r*r) exists in dict, and the count is increased by the number of instances of a pair in dictPairs.

Using the example provided and iterating step by step might give a clearer answer:

The first element in the reversed array is 64

- 256 (64*4) is not in dictPairs, nor is it in dict
- The pair (64, 1) is added to dict because it is not in dict yet and thus the default value of 0 is returned from dict.get(i, 0)

The second element in the array is 16

- 64 (16*4) is not in dictPairs, but it is in dict. Thus, (16, 1) is added to dictPairs, because dictPairs does not contain a 16 yet, and dict[64] is equal to one
- The pair (16, 1) is added to dict

The third element in the array is 4

- 16 (4*4) is in dictPairs! This means the count increases by one, because dictPairs[16] is equal to one
- 16 is also in dict, so the pair (16, 1) is added to dictPairs
- The pair (4, 1) is added to dict

The last element in the array is 1

- 4 is in dictPairs, so the count increases by one again, because dictPairs[4] is equal to one
- 4 is also in dict, so the pair (4, 1) is added to dictPairs
- the pair (1, 1) is added to dict

The count is then 2 because there are two triplets.

Comment: Thank you so much @jreiss 1923. I got it.

Comment: Can you explain me the meaning of this statement:                                                             if (i*r) exists in dictPairs, that means there is a triplet, because if (i*r) exists in dictPairs that must mean (i*r*r) exists in dict.

Comment: Your "dict" is checking to see how many instances of a certain number there are: if your list was [1, 4, 16, 64, 64], the final dict would have the pair (64, 2), because there are two instances of the number 64. 

Your dictPair is then checking to see if i and i\*r exist in dict. If it does, then i is added to dictPair. 

If i\*r is in dictPair, that must mean i\*r\*r exists, because dictPair checks to see if a number and that number \* r exist. If a number, that number \*r, and that number \*r\*r exist, there is a triplet.

If you don't mind please mark my answer as solved :)

Comment: Yeah, I got it.

Comment: can you suggest me the logic what should I do if I want the triplet pairs instead of count?

Comment: If you want to have a return of the triplet pairs, you could create an empty list instead of count, and instead of incrementing count you just have to append a new list with [i, i\*r, i\*r\*r]. Then when you reach the return statement you just have to return that list!

Comment: Not a problem if you have any more questions just comment below

Comment: I assume if you don't reverse the array you could use division instead of multiplication for the existence checks.  This is cleanest and clearest solution I have ever seen to this problem.

Comment: Can you expain it with [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] as an example?

Answer (score 1):

The above program makes use of the two dictionaries to keep track of the possible triplets;

Now, starting from the the end (since we have a given constraint i < j < k)

the dict keeps track of elements i and dictPairs keeps track of elements i*r.

Now, we check the following;

1. if an element i*r is present in dictPairs, if it is present then there exists a triplet (i, i*r, i*r*r)
2. if an element i*r is present in dict, if it is present the then there is a pair (i, i*r)
3. if it is present in neither of them we add it to dict, making it a candidate for future triplets

It is always recommended to trace an algorithm to gain better understanding how it works,

Assume we have an array [1,2,8,3,4,6,12] and given common ratio 2.

Now, starting from the end,

Initally;

```
dict = {}
dictPairs = {}
```

- Element 12 ==> check if 12*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in neither ==> add it to dict

  `dict = {12 : 1} dictPairs = {}`
- Element 6 ==> check if 6*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in dict ==> add it to dictPairs

  `dict = {12 : 1} dictPairs = {6 : 1}`
- Element 4 ==> check if 4*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in neither ==> add it to dict

  `dict = {12 : 1, 4 : 1} dictPairs = {6 : 1}`
- Element 3 ==> check if 3*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in dictPairs ==> increment count

  `dict = {12 : 1, 4 : 1} dictPairs = {6 : 1}`
- Element 8 ==> check if 8*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in neither ==> add it to dict

  `dict = {12 : 1, 4 : 1, 8 : 1} dictPairs = {6 : 1}`
- Element 2 ==> check if 2*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in dict ==> add it to dictPairs

  `dict = {12 : 1, 4 : 1, 8 : 1} dictPairs = {6 : 1, 2 : 1}`
- Element 1 ==> check if 1*2 is present in dict or dictPairs ==> present in dictPairs ==> increment count

  `dict = {12 : 1, 4 : 1, 8 : 1} dictPairs = {6 : 1, 2 : 1}`

You can see how triplet (2, 4 , 8) is not selected as they are not in order.

One thing to note is the clever use of the dict.get() function to add new entries.[check how dict.get() works](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get)

Comment: Your explained it quite well. You have taken an unsorted array. I provided a sorted one. Can you rectify this line below:                                                                                              
   dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1                                                                                                              I mean when the the element isn't present in dict or dictPairs, then it is added to dict. But there isn't any **if** condition for that. It means the line comes under for loop and it will be executed always. It won't check any condition.

Comment: Either the element is present in dict or dictPairs, it will always be added in dict. As you said dict is keeping tracks of i, then each element should be present in dict.

Comment: Can you expain it with [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] as an example?